# Will an HSA save me money on chiropractic or dental?

Tags: united-states, hsa

I live in NJ and have a full time Job. I am mid 35's and my friend is on mid 45's.

We both have our Health Insurance. However, it doesn't support Chiropractors or Dental.

Will having an HSA Account and spending money for Chiropractors or Dental through HSA Account save a little bit of tax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can pay for chiropractic and dental through an HSA. If you do this, you are essentially paying for these things with before-tax money. Your savings depend on which tax bracket you are in; for example, if you are in the 15% bracket, you will essentially save 15% on these expenses by contributing the money into an HSA, and then paying out of that account, instead of paying directly with after-tax money.

In order to be eligible to contribute to an HSA, you need to be enrolled in a High Deductible Health Plan (HDHP). If you don't know if your current health insurance plan is an HSA-eligible HDHP, you can ask your health insurance provider.

Comment: Just thought about this. On paying the full payment to my Chiropractors or Dentist through cash without using Insurance, How should i withdraw money from HSA Account?

Comment: As well as my Insurance provider mentioned that my annual deduction is $1000 for Tier 1 and $2000 for Tier 2 Hospitals. I am not sure whether this makes me qualified for HSA. I do know that Annual Deduction for a single person should be $1300. But this Tier 1 and Tier 2 confuses me.

Comment: @goofyui HSA accounts often come with checkbooks and debit cards that you can use to pay for medical expenses, or you can pay with your checking account or credit card and reimburse yourself.

Comment: @goofyui I'm not an expert on HDHPs, but a quick call to your insurance company will tell you if your current plan is HSA-eligible or not.